# Slow building excel worksheet using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am using the NPOI library to build Excel worksheets in an app that my supervisor wants to host on a Linux server.  The app works fine with files under 1000 rows but occasionally I have large files and it takes a lot longer than I would expect.  Does anyone have any idea how I can speed up the processing for these large files?  Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataMalformed.Rows)
            {
                IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

                //Console.WriteLine(row[0]);

                if (dataMalformed.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    strFileName = strMalformed + "\\MVPSMalformedProd" + "-";
                    strFileName2 = strFileName + strDate2 + ".xls";
                }

                var fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                var fs2 = new FileStream(strFileName2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                strSheetName = "Malformed Messages - " + ", " + strDate2;
                
                using (fs)
                {

                    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet(strSheetName);

                    intRow = 2;

                    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                    IRow row1 = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
                    int columnIndex = 0;

                    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in dataMalformed.Columns)
                    {
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
                        row1.CreateCell(columnIndex).SetCellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        columnIndex++;
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow row2 in dataMalformed.Rows)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(row2[0]);
                        row1 = excelSheet.CreateRow(intRow);
                        int cellIndex = 0;
                        foreach (String col in columns)
                        {
                            row1.CreateCell(cellIndex).SetCellValue(row2[col].ToString());
                            excelSheet.AutoSizeColumn(cellIndex);
                            cellIndex++;
                        }
                        
                        if (dictSenders.ContainsKey(row2[3].ToString()))
                        {
                            row1.CreateCell(--cellIndex).SetCellValue(dictSenders[row2[3].ToString()]);
                        }

                        intRow++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please provide the code in question and describe what you have tried to improve the performance.

Comment: I have tried researching the problem but all I can find is for Excel using the MIcrosoft Interop library.

Comment: Have you tried Spire.Doc for .NET, which is more efficient than Microsoft Interop library in processing Excel files? And, it provides a [free version](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-word-for-net-free.html) for developers to create .xlsx files without any restricton.

Comment: how long do you expect this to take?

Answer (score 0):

And you are sure that NPOI is the problem? I just tried the following to create an excel file with 10000 rows and 50 columns.

```
  var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook ();
  var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet ("Sheet1");

  for (var rowNum = 0; rowNum < 10000; rowNum++)
  {
    var rowData = sheet.CreateRow (rowNum);

    for (var columnNum = 0; columnNum < 50; columnNum++)
    {
      rowData.CreateCell (columnNum).SetCellValue ($"Row {rowNum + 1}, Column {columnNum + 1}");
    }
  }

  using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create ("D:\\Temp\\test.xlsx"))
  {
    workbook.Write (fileStream);
    fileStream.Close ();
  }
```

Comment: how long did it take?